# Pitch accent in Korean

Tags: pronunciation

Are there any resources for learning the pitch accents for words in Korean?

Additionally, how do you determine pitch accents for conjugated verbs and compound words?

Comment: http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/does-standard-korean-still-contain-any-signs-of-being-a-tonal-language may be of interest. South Kyungsang dialect is dealt with in https://linguistics.drupal.ku.edu/sites/linguistics.ku.edu/files/docs/Zhang/Lee-Zhang-JEAL-final.pdf

Comment: According to Wikipedia and another source, pitch accent still exists in Seoul Korean. Unless that died out with the vowel length distinction?

Comment: I've seen a few teachers on iTalki advertising that they can teach Gyeongsangdo accent. Here's an example: https://www.italki.com/teacher/2870534

Answer (score 5):

[That Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_accent#Korean)(now fixed) is mistaken. Seoul Korean lost its pitch accent system at least since the 17th Century. The article is citing nothing related to an evidence supporting an existence of a system-wide pitch accent in Seoul Korean.

> Pitch accent is a feature of certain languages whose variations in pitch (linguistic tones) can be used to differentiate words

To call something a pitch accent, it needs to distinguish words based only on pitch variations, in other words, it needs a minimal pair. Seoul Korean has none.

Seoul Korean determines its intonation based on Intonation Phrases, not words. So it is not pitch accented.

To read more about intonation in Seoul Korean, refer to:
[Intonational Phonology of Seoul Korean Revisited](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228581646_Intonational_phonology_of_Seoul_Korean_revisited).

Comment: Probably worth noting that the article has now been fixed.

Comment: @topomorto Oh! Did you fix it? Thanks

Comment: Not me -  I thought it might have been you! Maybe the OP?

Comment: Good job all around! :)