# Distinguish length of vowels?

Tags: phonology, vowel

I'm a native Korean speaker and have lived almost all my life in Seoul.
I have thought that distinguishing meanings of words by the lengths of vowels have almost disappeared.
But I recently heard that not distinguishing long and short vowels is a kind of 'dialect' of Seoul.
Is that true?

Can non-Seoulites distinguish 밤(night) and 밤(chestnut) only by the length of sounds?

Comment: 조사 없이 확신하기는 어렵겠으나 저라면 고령자나 발음에 신경 써야 하는 사람(성우, 아나운서, 국어 교사 등)을 제외하고 장단음을 구별하는 사람은 거의 없다고 하겠습니다. 잠시 시간을 내어 자료를 찾아보니 [경상도 대학생도 장단음을 구별하지 못할 듯합니다](http://fonetiks.info/bgyang/db/2015duration.pdf). 다른 지역 자료도 찾아보면 나오지 않을까 싶습니다.

Comment: I live in Busan. I and my friends can distinguish those two 밤, but not with 100% certainty. Also I am not sure whether this is because of length or tone/pitch (which, I heard, are also nonexistent or very weak in Seoul idalect). I personally feel like those two differ in both length and tone in Busan dialect, but others might not agree.

Comment: 밑에 질문 답변에서 서울 사람들은 장단음 구별 못하게 됐다고 한 거 보고 자존심 대결마냥 발동 걸린 느낌인데 그런가요? ㅋㅋ 저는 서울 사람인데 두 밤을 소리로 구별하라고 하면 솔직히 자신 없을 거 같아요. 경상도 방언 이용자들 역시도 세기로 단어를 구분하는 경향이 있을 뿐이지 장단음을 온전히 인지하는 사람은 드물 거라고 생각합니다.

Comment: 장단음 얘기가 나오면 제가 늘 하는 얘긴데, 한국 사람끼리 "거울과 겨울은 소리가 비슷하지만 주의깊게 발음하면 구분할 수 있어요" 같은 말 안 하잖아요? 누가 "겨울에 먼지 묻었어" 하면 "뭥미??' 하겠죠. 정말로 장단음의 구분이 존재한다면 마찬가지로 누가 "눈:에 먼지 들어갔어" 했을 때 "엥? 지금 눈: 와?" 같은 반응이 나올 겁니다. "주의깊게 들으면 구분이 가요"란 말은 그냥 자기암시죠.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is the Modern Seoul dialect losing its length distinction?**

Yes, length contrast is being neutralised in Seoul Korean. This is something that has been happening for a while:

- According to [Han (1964)](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/AD0605683), Seoul Korean speakers who were back then in their 20s and 30s, thus born in the 1930s/40s, had a robust distinction between long and short vowels. However, the set that was pronounced with long vowels in initial position was a bit smaller than the (newly-formed!) standard - long vowels were already becoming short vowels.
- The proportion of native Seoul speakers that retain the contrast reduces. [Kang (2015)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/lp-2015-0014/html) gives a good overview of many studies from the 1980s to 2010s; fewer younger speakers retain the length contrast, fewer female speakers than male speakers retain the contrast, and of those that do, the length contrast is operative for fewer words.
- There is also some hypercorrection going on with older speakers, according to Kim, S. (2003) in the [표준 발음 실태 조사 2](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/bookData/bookDataView.do;front=175B766EE4B3B19A3FFBD4C6E033EE3B?mn_id=104&book_seq=22&book_category_id1=&book_category_id2=16&pageIndex=1), as reported by [Kang (2015)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/lp-2015-0014/html).
- [Kang (2015)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/lp-2015-0014/html) finds that:

> the change is almost complete, such that the long/short ratio falls below 1:1 and plateaus out in the youngest speakers’ speech, suggesting that we are observing the end stage of an S-curve in this change.

- The study also reports that distinctions even between high-frequency words are being lost as fast or even faster than low frequency words.

Will the Seoul Korean of 2021 join Jeju-eo and the Hwanghae region in North Korea as having [neither](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_dialects#/media/File:Korean_prosodemes.svg) contrastive tone nor [length distinctions](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/does-standard-korean-still-contain-any-signs-of-being-a-tonal-language)? It is certainly a speech variety in great flux through the 2010s, with some studies suggesting that [it may](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0095447014000357) in the [future](http://speechlearning.lab.mcgill.ca/pdfs/Bang(JPhon_preprint).pdf) develop [lexical tone](https://scholarworks.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2268&context=honorstheses). Cho (2018) reports that there is already a contrast: the [high-toned 일](http://isli.khu.ac.kr/journal/content/data/35_3/5.pdf).

**Distinguishing By Length: Jeolla-do / Jeonnam 전라도/전남 사투리**

According to [the map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_dialects#/media/File:Korean_prosodemes.svg), more rural Central-region dialects, Pyeong'an dialects, and Jeolla dialects are the other ones that (traditionally) have phonemic vowel length. [Gyeongsang](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254658364_A_Note_on_Contrasts_Mergers_and_Acquisitions_in_Kyungsang_Accent) and Hamgyeong dialects generally also distinguish 밤〮 (night) vs 밤〯 (chestnut) by tone rather than length, much like Middle Korean is recorded as doing; having said that, at least in some Gyeongsang varieties, a difference in vowel length accompanies certain tones (rising tone specifically means longer length both [in Daegu and Busan](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254658364_A_Note_on_Contrasts_Mergers_and_Acquisitions_in_Kyungsang_Accent)).

As for Southern Jeolla (Jeonnam) dialects as reported by [Ko (2001)](https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1688&context=nels), the sample of three used born in the 1970s could all use "distinguish the short from the long vowel both in terms of perception and production". According to [Ha (2020)](http://www.papersearch.net/thesis/article.asp?key=3819678), it seems that Jeonnam teenagers born around 2000 have mostly lost the distinction too though.

There are studies that say that Southern Jeolla dialects (focusing on Gwangju) can be analysed as a system based on [phonemic stress](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272537364_A_metrical_theory_of_Korean_word_prosody) rather than vowel length. This position on [various changes](https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1688&context=nels) that happen to the length of words, as well as the [interaction](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/Events/PLC/plc23/ko.html) of "intensity" with length and pitch.