# Why does Wikipedia and Wiktionary list [mʷəː] as the pronunciation for 뭐?

Tags: pronunciation, hangul

I've noticed that some articles on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_phonology) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%AD%90) on Korean claim that the Korean word 뭐 is transcribed as [mwɘ(ː)] in IPA, with [ɘ] being the IPA symbol for the close-mid central unrounded vowel.

I'm confused by this claim. I'm not a linguist or a fluent Korean speaker — just a beginner student — but I've listened to multiple samples of Korean speech online and none sound anywhere close to [ɘ].

Some other sources, like [this IPA handbook](https://archive.org/details/rosettaproject_kor_phon-2/page/n3/mode/2up?view=theater%20this%20IPA%20handbook), on the other hand, list another pronunciation: /mwʌ/. You can also see this pronunciation used in some other Wikipedia entries.

I understand that the broad and the narrow transcriptions are different, but it really does sound much closer to [mwʌ] than [mwɘ].

So why do multiple Wikipedia/Wiktionary pages transcribe 뭐 as [mwɘ(ː)] in IPA?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I feel it may have to do with some incorrect assumptions of mine about how IPA and vowel charts work. Additionally, I noticed that some of the articles I linked designate the sound as a schwa ə, which feels more plausible than [ɘ]. Maybe this would be a better question for Linguistics SE, not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see that in *relatively* conservative standard Korean, e.g. from the 1996 국어 음성학 by 이호영, as found on [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Korean_vowel_chart.svg), the values of the short 어 and the long 어 are very different: the long 어 is much more central and a bit more closed than the short 어.

Looking at the vowel trapezoid, you can see that short 어 is between cardinal [ʌ] and cardinal [ɑ], and long 어 is much closer to cardinal [ɘ]. Hence the use of the notation /ʌ/ and /ɘː/.

The [1999 entry for Korean](https://archive.org/details/rosettaproject_kor_phon-2) in the IPA has the short 어 much closer to cardinal [ʌ] than [ɑ], but the long 어 is still near cardinal [ɘ]. However, for the long 어 that notation used /ʌː/ instead.

There is also a practical reason for phonologists who work with synchronic and diachronic varieties of Korean, as explained here in a footnote from a 2016 introduction to Korean phonology from [Young-mee Yu Cho](https://oxfordre.com/linguistics/linguistics/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780199384655.001.0001/acrefore-9780199384655-e-176#acrefore-9780199384655-e-176-note-8):

> However, I follow the general practice of using the symbol /ə/, even though the phonetic studies find this vowel to be quite back and lower-mid, on the basis of a common practice in Korean historical phonology, where the symbol /ʌ/ is reserved for the Arae-A vowel of Middle Korean that was lost in Modern Korean (except in Cheju Island).

The phonology of the Seoul accent of the modern 2020s is different though; with the [total loss of phonemic vowel length](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6419/distinguish-length-of-vowels) across the vast majority of speakers, the 어 vowel has ended up closer to cardinal [ʌ] - thus your perception is correct. [Figure 1.3 of Jiyoung Shin](http://media.public.gr/Books-PDF/9781118354919-1069377.pdf)'s chapter from the 2015 tome *The Handbook of Korean Linguistics* compares these modern Korean vowels specifically [to the recordings of cardinal vowels of Daniel Jones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UIAe4p2I74) from the 1910s.

It is mentioned that the lips are slightly more rounded for modern 어, hence the notation /ʌ̹/ with the rounding diacritic that can sometimes be seen in the literature. I've yet to see anyone quite dare to suggest that 어 has become [ɔ] in modern Seoul Korean, although this is already the case in 평안도 사투리 the Pyeong'an dialect, where there has been an 어 - 오 merger.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you so much! One question - I can't find the "long 어" on the chart that you linked in the first paragraph. It should be the [ʌː] sound, right?
I did find the short and the long vowel charts on [the Korean wiki page on phonetics](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%96%B4_%EC%9D%8C%EC%9A%B4%EB%A1%A0) though, and your explanation makes sense given those 2 charts.

Comment: @undercat On the Wikimedia link, it's represented as /əː/. It's really far from /ʌ/ isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, okay. In the [link](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%96%B4_%EC%9D%8C%EC%9A%B4%EB%A1%A0) from my previous comment (한국어 음운론), [ʌː] is located exactly where [əː] is in the [Wikimedia chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Korean_vowel_chart.svg) that you linked. So I guess "my" chart uses [ʌː] for the "long 어" while "your" chart uses [əː] for the same vowel.